# Using gcc atomic builtins?

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, atomic

I'm trying to use `__atomic_load_n` from the `gcc` [atomic builtins](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) page, compiling with

```
gcc -Wall -march=i686 -std=gnu99 ll.c -o ll
```

but it tells me it can't

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘__atomic_load_n’

I thought it would be enough to provide `gcc` with the `arch` and the `march` flags (and made sure by setting the `std=gnu99` flag), but to no avail. In fact, even if I test for the common `__GCC_VERSION__` or `__GNUC__` macros don't seem to have values... but I have a pretty vanilla `gcc` installation, the one that comes in Ubuntu.

I know I'm doing something silly, but I can't figure out what. I have gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Code looks like this: it's a function that never gets called (yet), so the problem is at compile time.

```
type* func(type* p) {
    type* q = __atomic_load_n (p, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that's giving you the error?

Comment: @NPE: sure, the questions has been updated.

Comment: I can compile your code no problem (gcc 4.7.2) once I typedef `type` to `int`. If you suspect a problem with your compiler installation, perhaps try to build a non-trival but clean project with it to see what happens?

Comment: @NPE: Oh, well. Looks like it's time to recompile gcc :( There goes an hour. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the `__atomic_*` functions were added in 4.7. Previous versions have `__sync_*` functions which fulfill a similar purpose.

Comment: as @KerrekSB said, this was introduced in GCC 4.7 Check GCC 4.6.3 documentation: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/

Comment: @KerrekSB: Since you were the first to say this, mind adding yours as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @DervinThunk: OK, done :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Up until GCC 4.6.3, compiler built-ins for atomic operations were a pure compiler extension, and in GCC they were grouped into the [`__sync_*`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) family of functions.

As of version 4.7.0, both the new C++11 and the C11 standards had been finalized, and GCC updated their atomic built-ins to better reflect the new memory model of those two new language revisions. The new functions are grouped into the [`__atomic_*`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) family.

However, the older built-ins are [still available](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html), and the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM) says this:

> It is **always** safe to replace a `__sync` call with an `__atomic` call using the `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` memory model.

Comment: While `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` is always valid, it may give you pretty suboptimal results, of couirse depending on the memory model of your CPU.

Comment: Thanks, well answered!